# Difference among the articles to be get published in journal, proceedings, magazines, transactions

Tags: mathematics, journals, paper-submission

I wrote some papers in my field (mathematics), but they differ in length. Most of my papers are on the longer end (50-100 pages) and the others are short (5-20 pages). I failed to find out that what is the exact journal for lengthy or shorter math papers. I decided to publish these papers either in journals or proceedings or magazines or transactions or bulletin or notes etc..

But the main problem is that most of these journals are length restricted.

So, what journal can I choose to publish long length paper or short length papers in? And what is the defference among proceedings, magazines, transactions, journal, notes, bulletin etc.?

Comment: Do you have an advisor?  Some other mentor?  This really isn't a question that can be answered in the abstract.

Comment: Every journal will state its length requirements somewhere in the submission materials. AMS also gives guidance overall for its various journals.